# Problem with compiling citation and bibliography on LaTeX for Mac (TeXSHOP)

Tags: citing

I am using LaTeX to write my thesis. Unfortunately my supervisor is a PC user and I am a Mac user. I am trying to use my supervisors codes, but it doesn't quite work. Can't find an answer that solves it yet (Probably my newness to this software) I used JabRef to create my bib file.

The following is a simplified block of code I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{chen2013evidence} found 

\newpage
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}
```

My bib file looks like this:

```
@Article{chen2013evidence,
  author    = {Chen, Yuyu and Ebenstein, Avraham and Greenstone, Michael and Li, Hongbin},
  title     = {Evidence on the impact of sustained exposure to air pollution on life expectancy from Chinaâs Huai River policy},
  journal   = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  year      = {2013},
  volume    = {110},
  number    = {32},
  pages     = {12936--12941},
  publisher = {National Acad Sciences},
}
```

I Typeset LaTeX once, then I Typeset BibTeX once, then I Typeset LaTex twice.

My aux file looks like this:

```
\relax 
\citation{chen2013evidence}
\bibdata{references}
\bibstyle{chicago}
```

Where my citation should be I get a [?], and no bibliography.
In my console I get an error that says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `chen2013evidence' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.
```

I am assuming that's the problem, but I have no idea why. I must be missing something obvious, maybe something specific to Mac?  Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also for verification, all my files are in the same folder.

Comment: (1) You should also get a file with extension `.blg`: what does it read?  (2) Open the Preferences window, select the Engine panel and look at the BibTeX Engine field: does it say “biber” or “bibtex”?

Comment: I did have problems compiling your file on a P.C. I suspect the problem comes from the accented character, which uses a different encoding on Mac and on a P.C. I suggest you both use  `biblatex+biber`, as there exists a `biblatex-chicago`  package, and encode in `utf8` (only universal encoding with ascii).

Answer (score 2):

as Bernard was hinting, there seems to be a missing package.

I added `\usepackage{chicacgo}` to your example and since then it worked.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chicago}
\begin{document}

\cite{chen2013evidence} found 

\newpage
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in this output:

[image]

Enjoy

Jan

Comment: Thank you Jan! I used the package and you are right, it works now.

Comment: Than, please be so kind, to mark your question as solved (any maybe ad a +vote :-)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. :-) Just for completeness, you may also want to make two additional suggestions, regarding the entry's `title` field: (a) Replace the funky-looking `â` character with `'`, and (b) encase the substring `China's Huai River` in a pair of curly braces, to keep BibTeX from lowercasing the initial letters of each of the three words.